# Вопрос про область видимости и работу оператора

Tags: c++

```
using namespace std;

int main(){
int b=0;
//bool b;// error
int cin;
cin>>cin;
cout<<cin;}
```

1 Вопрос: почему если мы подключили пространство имен, не возникает конфликта имен в int cin,ведь по идее cin уже определена где-то сверху с др типом? и почему как-то странно работает оператор >> ?

```
void operator>>(int& b, int& c) {
    b=c;
}
```

2 Вопрос: почему нельзя так перегрузить оператор?

Comment: 1) Имена во вложенной области видимости скрывают имена из внешней области видимости. Конфликтов не возникает. Можно написать так: `int i = 1; {int i = 2; cout << i;} cout << i;` 2) У перегруженного оператора хотя бы один операнд должен иметь классовый тип или тип перечисления. С одной стороны правила языка ограничивают полёт фантазии, и нельзя написать так: `int operator+ (int a, int b) {return a - b;}`. C другой стороны, наверное и хорошо, что нельзя.

Comment: *"если мы подключили пространство имен"* - потому что `using namespace std;` делает не то, что вы думаете, что оно делает. Конфликт имен возникает, однако С++ его неявно разрешает, так как имя `cin` первый раз появляется на уровень выше (shadowing). Напишите `using std::cin;` внутри `main` - получите ошибку.

Comment: @wololo а можете поподробнее объяснить про оператор, не совсем понятно

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Стандарт про **using namespace** :

> A **using**-directive specifies that the names in the nominated namespace
> can be used in the scope in which the **using**-directive appears after
> the **using**-directive. During unqualified name lookup (3.4.1), the names
> appear as if they were declared in the nearest enclosing namespace
> which contains both the **using**-directive and the nominated namespace. [
> Note: In this context, “contains” means “contains directly or
> indirectly”. — end note ]

Директива **using** указывает, что имена в указанном пространстве имен могут использоваться в области, в которой директива **using** появляется после директивы **using**. Во время поиска по неквалифицированным именам (3.4.1) имена отображаются так, как если бы они были объявлены в ближайшем охватывающем пространстве имен, которое содержит как директиву **using**, так и назначенное пространство имен. [Примечание: В данном контексте “содержит” означает “содержит прямо или косвенно”. — заключительная
записка ]

---

Про охватывающее пространство, пример с тремя отделами, локальная , охватывающая и именное :

```cpp
namespace My {
  int glob = 88 ;
}
using namespace My ;
char const * glob = "glob" ;
# include <iostream>
int main(){
  double glob = 7.77 ;
  std :: cout << "glob = " << glob << std :: endl ;
  std :: cout << "::glob = " << ::glob << std :: endl ;
  std :: cout << "My::glob = " << My::glob << std :: endl ;
}
```

```
glob = 7.77
::glob = glob
My::glob = 88
```

Выведется значение локальной переменной `7.77` так как она имеет бо'льший приоритет над охватывающим пространством *(глобальными переменными и именным пространством)*. При добавлении `::` выводится глобальная переменная. И при добавлении `My::` конечно выводится переменная из `My`. *Глобальные переменные и переменные из пространства `My` имеют одинаковые права.*

Удаляем глобальную переменную.

```cpp
namespace My {
  int glob = 88 ;
}
using namespace My ;
# include <iostream>
int main(){
  double glob = 7.77 ;
  std :: cout << "glob = " << glob << std :: endl ;
  std :: cout << "::glob = " << ::glob << std :: endl ;
  std :: cout << "My::glob = " << My::glob << std :: endl ;
}
```

```
glob = 7.77
::glob = 88
My::glob = 88
```

при `::` выводится значение переменной из именного пространства, так как такая запись означает использование внешнего пространства и мы указали её использовать.

Удаляем локальную переменную.

```cpp
namespace My {
  int glob = 88 ;
}
using namespace My ;
# include <iostream>
int main(){
  std :: cout << "glob = " << glob << std :: endl ;
  std :: cout << "::glob = " << ::glob << std :: endl ;
  std :: cout << "My::glob = " << My::glob << std :: endl ;
}
```

```
glob = 88
::glob = 88
My::glob = 88
```

При отсутствии конкурентов, локальных и глобальных переменных выводится значение из пространства имен `My` в любой записи.

При присутствии только глобальных переменных и использовании пространства имён происходит конфликт имён и остаётся прямое указание из какого пространства нужно брать переменную.

```cpp
namespace My {
  int glob = 88 ;
}
using namespace My ;
char const * glob = "glob" ;
# include <iostream>
int main(){
  // error: reference to 'glob' is ambiguous
  // std :: cout << "glob = " << glob << std :: endl ;
  std :: cout << "::glob = " << ::glob << std :: endl ;
  std :: cout << "My::glob = " << My::glob << std :: endl ;
}
```

```
::glob = glob
My::glob = 88
```

*почему если мы подключили пространство имен, не возникает конфликта имен в int cin*

Ваша переменная **cin** объявлена в локальном пространстве имён. Директива **using namespace** добавляет в охватывающее пространство. А локальное пространство имеет приоритет над охватывающем.

*почему как-то странно работает оператор **>>***

Локальная переменная **cin** имеет тип **int**, потому-что локальные переменные имеют приоритет на охватывающими. . Ничего странного, так как целое число при бинарном сдвиге возвращает новое целое число, которое вы благополучно игнорируете.
Чтобы выделить переменную из охватывающего пространства можно использовать **::**, тогда **::cin** будет тип потока, а **cin** локальная переменная.

```cpp
:: cin >> cin ;
```

*почему нельзя так перегрузить оператор*

> error: 'void operator<<(int&, int)' must have an argument of class or enumerated type

Ошибка говорит, что тип должен быть классом или перечислением. Всё дело в том, что встроенный тип **int** уже вшит в язык очень жёстко и новые определения операторов могут быть созданы только над новыми типами. Каким образом обычный оператор бинарного сдвига

```cpp
int x = 7 << 2 ;
// x == 28 ;
```

можно подменить на другое исполнение?

Comment: примеры переделал на более полезные ..